# Не сохраняется сессия

Tags: php, сессия

Не сохраняется сессия.

```
session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['count'])) {
   $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
} else {
   $_SESSION['count']++;
}
echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

при каждом обновлении показывает 1

снимок `phpinfo()`;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `session_start()` вам в помощь.

Comment: Путь session.save_path существует?

Comment: Да конечно, все верно

Comment: Там видно мои история сессии, и прова 777

Comment: попробуйте в начале скрипта объявить ob_start();

Comment: на mozzilа и на opera не работает. в чем дело?

Comment: Права на session.save_path смотрел? И что пишет лог?

Comment: session_start() не правильном месте поставлено было, нужно было в headere прописать, а я внутри кода поставил))